# How to add a custom tab in the user editing page

Tags: users, control-panel

I try to add a custom tab to user account editing page, but there is only one default tab called 'profile' to use and we are not allowed to add another tab there. I am just wondering if this is the case and if Craft CMS will allow us to add a custom tab there in future versions.

Thanks.
Spencer

Answer (score 2):

That's currently not natively possible in Craft, but this [feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests/suggestions/7850367-tabs-to-separate-user-profile-content) sounds like what you're looking for if you want to vote for it.